# Forcing Access 2007 to run Access 2000 app WITHOUT putting everything in tabs

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an old Access 2000 app (I don't do much Access dev these days) that a client is trying to run in Access 2007. It runs fine for the most part, except the forms do not behave as-designed when they are called/instantiated, etc: Access 2007 puts every new form inside a "Tab" of sorts, which is causing confusion on the part of the end user (modal forms they can't "tab out of," etc., seems to be the kind of thing they are mentioning).

It was designed as a typical MDI app, and ran fine that way for years. Is there a way to override Access 2007 "taking over" the forms handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Set Document Window Options to Overlapping Windows, then save the database (which should persist it to subsequent runs).

From [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP100913941033.aspx):

> By default, Microsoft Office Access
>   2007 databases display as tabbed
>   documents. To use windowed documents,
>   click the Microsoft Office Button
>   Button image, and then click Access
>   Options. In the Access Options dialog
>   box, click Current Database and, under
>   Document Window Options, click
>   Overlapping Windows.

More information about transitioning to Access 2007 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203849.aspx) as well.